# why is the element (12) in the group ring of $S_3$, $\mathbb{R}[S_3]$ a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> why is the element (12) in the group ring of $S_3$, $\mathbb{R}[S_3]$ a unit?

Since (12) is a unit, that means there's an element $a$ such that $(12)a = a(12) = 1$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity or unity.

What is $a$ then?

If I'm correct, I can say $$\mathbb{R}[S_3] = \{a_0e + a_1(12) + a_2(13) + a_3(23) + a_4(123)+a_5(132)\}$$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

$(12)$ is an element of this ring since if from $a_0$ to $ a_5$ are all zero except $a_1 = 1$, this makes (12).

Since the inverse of $(12)$ is itself and I just showed that $(12)$ is in the ring, $(12)$ is a unit.

This is my first time studying rings, so I'm not yet familiar with the stuff.

Is my thought correct?

Comment: It seems good to me

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου thanks for reviewing!

Comment: In general for any group $G$ and ring $R$, all the elements of $G$ are obviously units in $R[G]$ (since the ring multiplication extends the group multiplication.). It's a little bit disconcerting you were given something this advanced if this is "your first time studying rings."  Group rings are hardly in the first wave of examples (although they could be put in the second.)